# Can't have the value of a check box from HTML using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm facing a problem while trying to use a check box defined in my HTML code ! The check box is used to select RegEx search !

Here a screenshot of the Layout : [image]

This is the HTML code :

```
<div class="filter_1">
    Filter :
</div>


<div class="RegEx_1">
    <input type="checkbox"  name="check">
    <label for="RegEx_1"> RegEx</label>
</div>

<form class ="search_1" name="search" action="/search" method="GET">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search_11">
    <input class="btn_1" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The python code (route to call) :

```
@app.route('/search', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def search():
results1=[]
res=""
q = request.args.get('search_11')
regex_check = request.form.get('check')

if regex_check : 
    res = "the box is checked"

elif q != "" :
    for i in kitt_list:
        if q in i :
            results1.append(i)
    for j in range(len(results1)):
        res = res + "\n" + results1[j]

return render_template('search.html', res=res, q=q)
```

Here are also the "search.html" :

```
<div class="title_1">
    Search results in <U>Kitt debug UART</U> for : " <mark>{{ q }}</mark> " 
</div>

<div id="searchterm" class="search_results">
    {{ res }}
</div>
```

The checkbox is always marked as unchecked !
Please provide me with any possible solutions !

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed a key thing from your POST. Your checkbox is outside of the form!

Submitting the form will always submit a value for checkbox.

When it is checked, the value will be `'on'`. When it is unchecked, it will be an empty string i.e. `""`

Comment: Even when I've changed the condition to `if regex_check == 'on' :` I still having the same problem

Comment: Print out the value when the box is checked and the value when it is unchecked. What are they?

Comment: It's `None` in both cases

Comment: I've tried making a condition this way : `checked = "check" in request.form` it's returning False

Comment: oh, i just realized your form method is a GET. Change it to a POST and it should work now. You can use ```request.values.get(<variable_name>)``` to retrieve values if you have issues with getting the values after changing your form method to a POST

Comment: The form used in HTML is changed to POST : `<form class ="search_1" name="search" action="/search" method="POST">` and in Python route both methods are allowed as shown : `@app.route('/search', methods =["GET", "POST"])` but still get a None return!

Comment: It working when I'm calling the value of the search_box as showed in the post ! When trying to get the value of the checkbox it's returning False

Comment: Thanks it was the right answer ! my check box was outside the form ! Now it's working ! Many Thanks !!